# Can someone help me to edit a tag wiki?

Tags: support, tag-wiki

I have created a new tag in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64623069/why-cant-i-make-use-of-this-srtp-that-i-have-defined) question, but I am unable to provide the details on what it means in the tag wiki. It won't let me add it to the edit queue either; I keep getting told the edit queue is full.
The tag is called 'srtp' and it means

> SRTPs (Statically Resolved Type Parameters) are a feature of F# which allow the programmer to specify behaviors of type parameters. These type parameters are then replaced with actual types at compile time instead of at run time.

Comment: Just wait until the edit queue is not full, try again in 15 min or so, most users have to suggest edits for tag wikis, the reputation threshold for editing them directly is quite high. That said, I'd expect SRTP to Secure Real-time Transport Protocol, not what you've said

Comment: This is why abbreviations are bad in tags. They're ambiguous.

Comment: @Catija I was about to disagree with you. Then I googled "SRTP" and I see that it also stands for "Secure Real-Time Transport Protocol". Is there a limit on long a tag can be? If not, how can I change this tag to `statically-resolved-type-paramter`?

Comment: 35 characters. If this is the only usage, just remove it and create the new tag. The existing one will self-destruct tomorrow.

Comment: In other news, I still find it incredibly annoying that I have Tag Wiki edit privileges, but cannot unilaterally approve a Tag Wiki edit suggestion, nor can I make my own edit if a suggested edit is in play.